# Можно ли перевести число из десятичной системы в двоичную не используя циклы

Tags: java, циклы

Собственно весь вопрос в заголовке.

Comment: Весь ответ в слове: нельзя. А с циклами Вы можете это сделать?

Comment: Тогда может вы подскажете как быть с заданием? "Реализовать функционал, который принимает на вход число (в диапазоне от 0 до 255) и выводит на экран его двоичное представление (нельзя использовать циклы, почитайте про оператор % в java)"

Comment: А-а-а, значит все-таки речь идет о *представлении* числа. Такие вещи надо помещать вопрос.

Comment: `Integer.toBinaryString(int i)` или `Integer.toString(int i, int radix)`

Comment: От вас хотят рекурсии

Comment: Какое задание, такая и программа. Поскольку числа от 0 до 255 вмещаются в 8 бит, то просто напишите 8 раз вывод 0 или 1 в зависимости от состояния бита (сначала 7-го, а в конце 0-го)

Answer (score 3):

Нельзя циклы - используйте рекурсию:

```
private static void printBinary(int val) {
    if (val < 2){
        System.out.print(val);
        return;
    }
    int digit = val % 2;
    printBinary(val / 2);
    System.out.print(digit);
}

printBinary(1); System.out.println();   // 1
printBinary(2); System.out.println();   // 10
printBinary(7); System.out.println();   // 111
printBinary(254); System.out.println(); // 11111110
printBinary(255); System.out.println(); // 11111111
```

Аналогичный вопрос с [enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14784630/converting-decimal-to-binary-java)